# Data Analysis with Outliers

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is supposed to return statistical analysis of approx 65 columns of data (questions from a survey).  Sample data is given below, as well as the current code.  Currently, the output only shows the columns that have no strings included (for the others, they return as NaN and don't even show up in the Excel).

I believe the issue is resulting from some of the data points being marked with 'No Data' and some marked with 'Outlier'

I'd like to learn a way to ignore the outlier/no data points and display statistics such as mean or median for the rest of the data.  I'd also love to learn how to incorporate conditional functions to display results such as 'count of responses > 4.25' so that I can expand on the analysis.

```
Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6
4.758064516 4.709677419 4.629032258 Outlier 4.708994709 4.209677419
4.613821138 No Data 4.259259259 4.585774059 4.255927476 Outlier
4.136170213 4.309322034 4.272727273 4.297169811 No Data 4.29468599
4.481558803 4.581476323 4.359495445 4.558252427 4.767926491 3.829030007
4.468085106 4.446808511 4.425531915 4.446808511 4.423404255 4.14893617
```

Sample Desired Output (doesnt correlate to sample data):
[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import ExcelWriter

# Pull in Data
path = r"C:\Users\xx.xx\desktop\Python\PyTest\Pyxx.xlsx"
sheet = 'Adjusted Data'
data = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=sheet)

#Data Analysis
analysis = pd.DataFrame(data.agg(['count','min','mean', 'median', 'std']), columns=data.columns).transpose()
print(analysis)

g1 = data.groupby('INDUSTRY').median()
print(g1)
g2 = data.groupby('New Zone').median()
print(g2)

#Excel
path2 = r"C:\Users\xx.xx\desktop\Python\PyTest\Pyxx2.xlsx"
writer = ExcelWriter(path2)
g1.to_excel(writer,'x')
g2.to_excel(writer,'y')
analysis.to_excel(writer,'a')
data.to_excel(writer,'Adjusted Data')
writer.save()
```

**EDIT**
Count how many of the responses to Q1 are > X (in this case, K1 = COUNTIF(K1:K999,TRUE))

[image]

I want this the values found in K1 & M1 (and so on for all of the questions) to be added to the analysis table like below:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This happens exactly because of the Strings. Thay cannot be summed with double numbers. It is an undefined operation hence the Nan.

Comment: I am looking to summarize all non-string values across each column.. Is that possible?  Also, will blanks be treated as zero during the analysis?

Answer (score 3):

This happens exactly because of the Strings. Thay cannot be summed with double numbers. It is an undefined operation hence the Nan.

Try and cleanup the data.

Options are:

- Drop the rows that contain no data or outliers if this makes sense in your statistic. (You can do that even one column at a time, computing statistics for one column at a time).
- Substitute those values with the mean of that column (this is one of the standard procedures in statistics).
- Think of a domain specific way to treat this kind of data.

Anyway I would try to remove the strings from the data.

If you cannot do that, it probably means that this data doesn't belong together with the rest because it comes from a different distribution.

Comment: Good insights here - I will most likely create two sheets (one to maintain the outliers vs missing data, and one to accommodate one of these strategies).  Do you have any thoughts on how to create a custom measure to find the count of entries > 4.25 (as an example)?

Comment: @RCarmody Once you have your data in a pandas DataFrame you can do whatever you want... Just look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833763/pandas-count-number-of-elements-in-each-column-less-than-x

Comment: @RCarmody if this is not what you meant, then I might have misunderstood your definition of custom measure.

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpreting this (i'm relatively new to python), but I am trying to add a new column in the screenshotted table above that represents the number of responses above a certain value.  In my limited experience with the agg function, I can only see how to add pre-existing functions ('mean','median',etc).

Comment: @RCarmody can you try and explain a little bit better what you want to do? Can you make an example using the data provided in the question? To my understanding you want to find, for example, the number of raws that have value > x, where x is a number in R, in the column Y, where Y is the name of a column. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: I've added in more information into the question (below the EDIT notation).  This is an excel output of what I am hoping to do... I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @RCarmody It still isn't clear for me... I am sorry... What do you mean by response? Value? or columns? But most importantly, why do you want to put everything in one and the same table? Can't you use different tables and sheets (if you want to speak excel) or not always use the DataFrame and use normal variables and other DataFrames (if you want to speak code)?

Comment: @RCarmody You can alway combine this data later, according to different parameters, between the different tables.